# Unable to exclude a property from the AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I have the following code inside my asp.net console application:-

```
Contact contact = new Contact()
     {
        Salutation = fields[SalutationIndex],
        FirstName = fields[FirstNameIndex],
        LastName = fields[LastNameIndex],
        Organization = fields[OrganizationIndex],
        Title = fields[TitleIndex]};

        var dbcontact = entities.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email.ToLower() == contact.Email.ToLower());
        Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, Contact>().ForSourceMember(x => x.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
        dbcontact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(contact);
        entities.Entry(dbcontact).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

now i want to copy all the properties from the `contact` to the `dbcontact`, but to exclude the ID, as inside the `contact` the ID will have the defualt value = `0` , while i want the `ID` to stay the one retrieved from the database.
but the above code will modify the `dbcontact` properties including the `ID` to be equal to the ones inside the `contact`.. so seems trying to ignore the `ID` did not work. 
I am using auto mapper 3.3.0 + console application is using asp.net 4.5 + Entity framework 5.0
Regards

Comment: Have you tried `ForMember` instead of `ForSourceMember`?

Comment: @DiskJunky same problem.. could the reason be that i need to explicitly define the ID inside the `contact`

Comment: Are you calling `Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, Contact>` before this call e.g., setting the binding elsewhere before this is called?

Comment: @DiskJunky do u think this could be the problem ? i do not think so

Comment: @DiskJunky so you mean to move it to be the first statement ?

Comment: I mean that AutoMapper (I'm assuming it's an old version as the latest is instance driven), is using the `static` call to `CreateMap`. If this the case then setting up the bindings is something to be done at application startup, not each time you need it. It could be that you've already already set mapping for that type before this code is hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong method. Try this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, Contact>().ForMember(x => x.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
Mapper.Map<Contact, Contact>(contact, dbcontact);
```

Look at the summary from this method.

> Execute a mapping from the source object to the existing destination object.

Edit:

Replace this 2 lines (from your example) with those from the answer:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, Contact>().ForSourceMember(x => x.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
dbcontact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(contact);
```

Comment: so you mean no need to do this `dbcontact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(contact);`??

Comment: `dbcontact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(contact);` So I think this creates a new object and set `ID` to default value.

Comment: so you mean the 2 lines of code you mentioned, does not need `dbcontact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(contact);`??

Comment: Update my answer